# Cloudant: Query search index with 2 parameters

Tags: node.js, express, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I wan to call the API with 2 parameters: **provider_id** and **id**, but I don't know the structure to call. It's clear how to do it with 1 parameter. Could you give me advice for this? Thanks.

This is the structure to call API with 1 param.

```
db.search('allstaff', 'allstaff_index', {q:"provider_id:"+request.params.provider_id}, function(err, doc) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloudant search query syntax is based on the Lucene syntax.

The available logical operators are: `AND`, `+`, `OR`, `NOT` and `-`, and are case sensitive.

Your query will looks like

> "provider_id:"+request.params.provider_id+" AND id:"+request.params.id

You can read more about in this [tutorial](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/).

Or watching this [video](https://youtu.be/8_knCoGbYbI)

Best regards

Bernardo Baumblatt